# Find exception line from Stacktrace in new version of code?

Tags: android-studio, stack-trace

When I receive error Stacktrace either via Play Developer console or via Crashlytics, it looks something like this

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
        at org.xxx.yyy.MainActivity.myMethod(MainActivity.java:483)
```

I can paste this content in Android Studio (`Analyze -> Analyze Stracktrace`) to get the Logcat output of the error.

The hard time happens when I click on the line 483 and it directs me to the empty space or some other method, because **I changed that class after the reporting version was released** and previous line 483 is now line 555 or 444. I then have to use the common sense to find the line in question.

[image]

Is there a way that Android Studio compares the Stacktrace with the current code and navigate me to the **line 483 which existed when the release package was created**? So I don't waste time searching where was the error line 7 days or 1 month ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I then have to use the common sense to find the line in question.

Or you can VCS here. If Crashlytics reports that the error was in 483-th line of `MainActivity` in the version 1.2.3 of your app, all you need to do is find the last commit made in 1.2.3 branch, update to this revision and take a look at the code in line №483.

Comment: That is another option as well which I will hopefully try to avoid.

Comment: I will mark this as an answer until the better one arrives.